# Here API: Getting wrong transit route information using the Android sdk

Tags: here-api

I try to fetch a basic transit route using the Android sdk but I'm missing data I need.

Basically, I want to get the exact same data as the Here We Go planner. Where you can see the steps, their departure and arrival time, which type of transit and which platform it departs or arrives.

So when I try to use RoutePlan in the Android sdk it gives me a wrong tta, it's like an hour longer than what it should be without any additional steps so far I can see. It also does not show the platforms and departure/arrival times of steps. The same applies for sending a route request to the route api in Postman.

My question is, how can I retrieve the exact same data as the Here We Go planner and app using the Android sdk?

Update: my Here project page also says 'Estimated Public Transit' for the majority of my requests, is this how it is supposed to be or should this be something else?

Update 2: I have tried using the here we go maps [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGlwx.png), postman [code below] and android sdk [code below] for the same route and got very different results.

Postman request: https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id=*app_id*&app_code=*app_code*&waypoint0=52.3146653,5.0248838&waypoint1=52.6381,4.740599999999972&departure=now&mode=fastest;publicTransport&combineChange=true

With result:

```
{
"response": {
    "metaInfo": {
        "timestamp": "2019-06-18T07:59:29Z",
        "mapVersion": "8.30.97.151",
        "moduleVersion": "7.2.201923-3839",
        "interfaceVersion": "2.6.58",
        "availableMapVersion": [
            "8.30.97.151"
        ]
    },
    "route": [
        {
            "waypoint": [
                {
                    "linkId": "-54239714",
                    "mappedPosition": {
                        "latitude": 52.3146951,
                        "longitude": 5.0248396
                    },
                    "originalPosition": {
                        "latitude": 52.3146653,
                        "longitude": 5.0248837
                    },
                    "type": "stopOver",
                    "spot": 1,
                    "sideOfStreet": "left",
                    "mappedRoadName": "Pampuslaan",
                    "label": "Pampuslaan",
                    "shapeIndex": 0,
                    "source": "user"
                },
                {
                    "linkId": "-1208098680",
                    "mappedPosition": {
                        "latitude": 52.6384828,
                        "longitude": 4.740455
                    },
                    "originalPosition": {
                        "latitude": 52.6381,
                        "longitude": 4.7406
                    },
                    "type": "stopOver",
                    "spot": 0.247191,
                    "sideOfStreet": "left",
                    "mappedRoadName": "Kruseman van Eltenweg",
                    "label": "Kruseman van Eltenweg",
                    "shapeIndex": 288,
                    "source": "user"
                }
            ],
            "mode": {
                "type": "fastest",
                "transportModes": [
                    "publicTransport"
                ],
                "trafficMode": "disabled",
                "feature": []
            },
            "leg": [
                {
                    "start": {
                        "linkId": "-54239714",
                        "mappedPosition": {
                            "latitude": 52.3146951,
                            "longitude": 5.0248396
                        },
                        "originalPosition": {
                            "latitude": 52.3146653,
                            "longitude": 5.0248837
                        },
                        "type": "stopOver",
                        "spot": 1,
                        "sideOfStreet": "left",
                        "mappedRoadName": "Pampuslaan",
                        "label": "Pampuslaan",
                        "shapeIndex": 0,
                        "source": "user"
                    },
                    "end": {
                        "linkId": "-1208098680",
                        "mappedPosition": {
                            "latitude": 52.6384828,
                            "longitude": 4.740455
                        },
                        "originalPosition": {
                            "latitude": 52.6381,
                            "longitude": 4.7406
                        },
                        "type": "stopOver",
                        "spot": 0.247191,
                        "sideOfStreet": "left",
                        "mappedRoadName": "Kruseman van Eltenweg",
                        "label": "Kruseman van Eltenweg",
                        "shapeIndex": 288,
                        "source": "user"
                    },
                    "length": 57000,
                    "travelTime": 7637,
                    "maneuver": [
                        {
                            "position": {
                                "latitude": 52.3146951,
                                "longitude": 5.0248396
                            },
                            "instruction": "Head <span class=\"heading\">south</span> on <span class=\"street\">Pampuslaan</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Go for <span class=\"length\">99 m</span>.</span>",
                            "travelTime": 109,
                            "length": 99,
                            "id": "M1",
                            "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
                        },
                        {
                            "position": {
                                "latitude": 52.3138046,
                                "longitude": 5.024904
                            },
                            "instruction": "Turn <span class=\"direction\">left</span> onto <span class=\"next-street\">Gemeenschapspolderweg</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Go for <span class=\"length\">887 m</span>.</span>",
                            "travelTime": 912,
                            "length": 887,
                            "id": "M2",
                            "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
                        },
                        {
                            "position": {
                                "latitude": 52.3131716,
                                "longitude": 5.0369418
                            },
                            "instruction": "Turn <span class=\"direction\">left</span> onto <span class=\"next-street\">Jan Campertplein</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Go for <span class=\"length\">98 m</span>.</span>",
                            "travelTime": 110,
                            "length": 98,
                            "id": "M3",
                            "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
                        },
                        {
                            "position": {
                                "latitude": 52.3137081,
                                "longitude": 5.0380576
                            },
                            "instruction": "Turn <span class=\"direction\">right</span> onto <span class=\"next-street\">E. du Perronstraat</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Go for <span class=\"length\">338 m</span>.</span>",
                            "travelTime": 349,
                            "length": 338,
                            "id": "M4",
                            "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
                        },
                        {
                            "position": {
                                "latitude": 52.3127103,
                                "longitude": 5.0419629
                            },
                            "instruction": "Turn <span class=\"direction\">right</span> onto <span class=\"next-street\">Stationsplein</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Go for <span class=\"length\">21 m</span>.</span>",
                            "travelTime": 32,
                            "length": 21,
                            "id": "M5",
                            "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
                        },
                        {
                            "position": {
                                "latitude": 52.3125601,
                                "longitude": 5.0421453
                            },
                            "instruction": "Turn <span class=\"direction\">left</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Go for <span class=\"length\">133 m</span>.</span>",
                            "travelTime": 133,
                            "length": 133,
                            "id": "M6",
                            "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
                        },
                        {
                            "position": {
                                "latitude": 52.312485,
                                "longitude": 5.0435722
                            },
                            "instruction": "Go to the station <span class=\"station\">Weesp</span> and take the <span class=\"transit\">train</span> <span class=\"line\">Sprinter</span> toward <span class=\"destination\">Amsterdam Centraal</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Follow for <span class=\"stops\">4 stations</span>.</span>",
                            "travelTime": 1915,
                            "length": 13021,
                            "id": "M7",
                            "stopName": "Weesp",
                            "_type": "PublicTransportManeuverType"
                        },
                        {
                            "position": {
                                "latitude": 52.3787248,
                                "longitude": 4.9008143
                            },
                            "instruction": "Get off at <span class=\"station\">Amsterdam Centraal</span> and change to the <span class=\"transit\">train</span> <span class=\"line\">Intercity</span> toward <span class=\"destination\">Alkmaar</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Follow for <span class=\"stops\">4 stations</span>.</span>",
                            "travelTime": 3095,
                            "length": 41444,
                            "id": "M8",
                            "stopName": "Amsterdam Centraal",
                            "_type": "PublicTransportManeuverType"
                        },
                        {
                            "position": {
                                "latitude": 52.6377726,
                                "longitude": 4.7408044
                            },
                            "instruction": "Get off at <span class=\"station\">Alkmaar</span>.",
                            "travelTime": 0,
                            "length": 0,
                            "id": "M9",
                            "stopName": "Alkmaar",
                            "_type": "PublicTransportManeuverType"
                        },
                        {
                            "position": {
                                "latitude": 52.6377726,
                                "longitude": 4.7408044
                            },
                            "instruction": "Head <span class=\"heading\">southeast</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Go for <span class=\"length\">367 m</span>.</span>",
                            "travelTime": 378,
                            "length": 367,
                            "id": "M10",
                            "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
                        },
                        {
                            "position": {
                                "latitude": 52.637794,
                                "longitude": 4.7458577
                            },
                            "instruction": "Turn <span class=\"direction\">left</span> onto <span class=\"next-street\">Helderseweg</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Go for <span class=\"length\">208 m</span>.</span>",
                            "travelTime": 217,
                            "length": 208,
                            "id": "M11",
                            "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
                        },
                        {
                            "position": {
                                "latitude": 52.6396501,
                                "longitude": 4.7454929
                            },
                            "instruction": "Turn <span class=\"direction\">left</span> onto <span class=\"next-street\">Kruseman van Eltenweg</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Go for <span class=\"length\">384 m</span>.</span>",
                            "travelTime": 387,
                            "length": 384,
                            "id": "M12",
                            "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
                        },
                        {
                            "position": {
                                "latitude": 52.6384828,
                                "longitude": 4.740455
                            },
                            "instruction": "Arrive at <span class=\"street\">Kruseman van Eltenweg</span>. Your destination is on the left.",
                            "travelTime": 0,
                            "length": 0,
                            "id": "M13",
                            "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "publicTransportLine": [
                {
                    "lineName": "Sprinter",
                    "companyName": "",
                    "destination": "Amsterdam Centraal",
                    "type": "trainRegional",
                    "id": "L1"
                },
                {
                    "lineName": "Intercity",
                    "companyName": "",
                    "destination": "Alkmaar",
                    "type": "trainRegional",
                    "id": "L2"
                }
            ],
            "summary": {
                "distance": 57000,
                "baseTime": 7637,
                "flags": [
                    "noThroughRoad",
                    "builtUpArea",
                    "privateRoad"
                ],
                "text": "The trip takes <span class=\"length\">57.0 km</span> and <span class=\"time\">2:07 h</span>.",
                "travelTime": 7637,
                "departure": "2019-06-18T09:59:29+02:00",
                "_type": "PublicTransportRouteSummaryType"
            }
        }
    ],
    "language": "en-us"
}
```

}

Logging the departure time and duration of the route in Android resulted in:
I/Departure time: 10:00
I/Duration: 02:51

Using the following code snippets:
Planning:

```
       RoutePlan routePlan = new RoutePlan();

    RouteOptions routeOptions = new RouteOptions();
    routeOptions.setTransportMode(RouteOptions.TransportMode.PUBLIC_TRANSPORT);
    routeOptions.setRouteType(RouteOptions.Type.FASTEST);
    routeOptions.setRouteCount(3);
    routeOptions.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
    if (toggleSwitch.getCheckedTogglePosition() == 0) {
        routeOptions.setTime(selected_time, RouteOptions.TimeType.DEPARTURE);
    }
    else {
        // Arrival time
    }
    routePlan.setRouteOptions(routeOptions);

    // Select Waypoints for your routes
    routePlan.addWaypoint(new RouteWaypoint(start_address_coordinate));
    routePlan.addWaypoint(new RouteWaypoint(end_address_coordinate));
    router.calculateRoute(routePlan, new RouterListener());
```

Result listener:

```
  private final class RouterListener implements CoreRouter.Listener {

    // Method defined in Listener
    public void onProgress(int percentage) {
        // Display a message indicating calculation progress
    }

    // Method defined in Listener
    public void onCalculateRouteFinished(List<RouteResult> routeResult, RoutingError error) {
        // If the route was calculated successfully
        if (error == RoutingError.NONE) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            planButton.setEnabled(true);

            Long start_time = routeResult.get(0).getRoute().getManeuvers().get(0).getStartTime().getTime();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
            String start_date = sdf.format(new Date(start_time));

            Date duration = new Date(routeResult.get(0).getRoute().getTtaIncludingTraffic(Route.WHOLE_ROUTE).getDuration() * 1000);

            Log.i("Departure time", start_date);
            Log.i("Duration", sdf.format(duration));
        }
        else {
            // Display a message indicating route calculation failure
            Log.e("Route Calculation ERROR", error.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In general, the portal 'https://wego.here.com' is using slightly different services and data releases. This depends also on the architecture. The SDKs e.g. have an offline possibility. But can you provide us an example for an analysis?

Comment: I edited the question and added my findings of using the here wego planner, postman and the android sdk for retrieving the exact same route. As you can see, the results are very different. The planner states only 1:20 duration, postman says 2:07 and the android sdk says 2:51.

Answer (score 0):

According the documentation on [PT of HERE Routing API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/public-transport-routing.html):

The Routing API calculates public transport routes in one of two ways:

- Estimated Routing – uses aggregated data to estimate a route.
- Timetable Routing – uses dynamic data to provide a more precise,
  detailed route.

How is deference of both above you can play on http://refclient.ext.here.com/

According the documentation for [Android mSDK](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/routing-transit.html) you can calculate transit routes using known online **timetable** information but this feature SDK-Route-PT-Timetable *doesn't enabled for Freemium account*(still not in the documentation yet, sorry for that) therefore for Freemium credentials will be used Estimated Routing(not Timetable Routing) and results will be corresponded to results of Routing API Estimated Routing for Public Transport.(Keep in mind for Routing API set please departure time parameter otherwise should be used TimeTable by default for calculation)

if you want to have the feature SDK-Route-PT-Timetable in your mSDK then contact us for more details on:

[Service Support](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/common/support-general.html)

[Contact to HERE](https://developer.here.com/contact-us)